# I can't install any Visual Studio on Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Is there any version of Windows IDE that is compatible Windows 7 Ultimate? Because i've been stuck with Code::blocks and i can't use Visual basic 2010 Express for C++ if there is none, Then is there any good IDE that is similar to Microsoft Visual Studios?

Thanks A LOT!

Comment: Why can't you install Visual Studio on Win7 ? i'm on Win7 Ultimate with Visual Studio 2015 Pro, are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Yea it says i need newer version of Windows =/

Comment: SharpDevelop, MonoDevelop will helpful